# How to git rebase using the hash instead of the branch name?

Tags: git, hash, branch, git-svn, git-rebase

I use `git rebase --onto target source foo` to move the branch `foo` from the branch `source` onto the branch `target`. Do you know if it is possible to use **hash values** instead of branch names (if not given) like this: `git rebase --onto ab91c f4242 foo`?
As a workaround I temporarily added branch names to the relevant commit objects. But this can be a pita if you have many branches to being rebased.

Example situation:

```
° bb42a
° ab91c
° 979c2
          /° fb648 foo
° f4242 --
° 333c9
```

After `git rebase --onto ...`

```
° bb42a
          /° fb648 foo
° ab91c --
° 979c2
° f4242
° 333c9
```

Background:
The explained problem is very common if you use an svn-server as you remote repository. All you commit objects get rewritten since the **svn-id** will be added every time you `git svn dcommit` to the svn-repository. This detaches all other branches from their former *master*.

Comment: What error message did you get when you tried using hash values? The git rebase man page does mention "May be any valid commit, and not just an existing branch name. "

Comment: I only tried this in the svn-scenario. I just tried it with a local git repository. It works. I will try it with svn tomorrow. There was an error message something like "Index object not found" but I have to reproduce it to state the message exactly.

Comment: ok I will check back tomorrow then ;) Note that `git svn rebase`is quite different from `git rebase`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is sure:

- a `git rebase` (not a `git-svn rebase`) can accept any valid commit as an argument, so hash values will work.
- The [caveat section](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_caveats) of `git-svn` does warn you of:

> avoid all `git clone`/`pull`/`merge`/`push` operations between git repositories and branches.
>   The recommended method of exchanging code between git branches and users is `git format-patch` and `git am`, or just 'dcommit’ing to the SVN repository.

So you need to make sure to not introduce commits in a SVN-synchronized branch which wouldn't know about that commit and would report as such.
(you have the opposite case in the SQ question "[`git svn` - `<file>` was not found in commit `<hash>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330202/git-svn-file-was-not-found-in-commit-hash)")

Comment: I probably did something wrong yesterday. Git rebase with hash values works. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @JJD: excellent. It is always useful, as soon as any error message pops up, to copy both the command and the error message in some temp file text. It can come in handy in question like this one ;)