# git svn clone: <file> was not found in commit <sha>

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, codeplex

I am trying to `git svn clone` the SSH.NET repository from Codeplex. My command is:

```
git svn clone https://sshnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/
```

But it always stops with an error message. This is my first time got an error during `git svn clone`, I don't know how this SVN repository is special.

I have tried to google for an answer, but nothing I found was working for me.
I have read:

- [git svn - <file> was not found in commit <hash>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4330202/1011174)
- [How do I resolve a git-svn index mismatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4073956/1011174)
- http://orville.thebennettproject.com/articles/git-troubleshooting/

Here's the error message:

```
r9445 = e8eb2162b4e5cc6b5b5129f0739c4f60cc42a58a (refs/remotes/git-svn)
        M       Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/Sftp/SftpFileStream.cs
        M       Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/Sftp/SftpFile.cs
        M       Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/SshCommand.cs
        M       Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/Shell.cs
        M       Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/SftpClient.cs
        M       Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/PrivateKeyFile.cs
        M       Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/ConnectionInfo.cs
r9486 = 91aea22d35ad41f70fa583d262438cf00a0a117d (refs/remotes/git-svn)
        M       Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/Security/Cryptography/Ciphers/RsaCi
pher.cs
        A       Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/Security/Cryptography/RsaKey.cs
Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/Security/Cryptography/RsaDigitalSignature.cs was no
t found in commit 91aea22d35ad41f70fa583d262438cf00a0a117d (r9486)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or work around to this problem? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git svn fetch --ignore-path hoge
```

`hoge` is the path of your file which has an error. (Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/Security/Cryptography/RsaDigitalSignature.cs)