# HOw do I get past the "Penultimate record is all-zeroes" issue?

Tags: git-svn

After I was required to update my password on a remote SVN server, I'm getting this error on all git-svn operations:

```
Penultimate record is all-zeroes in .git/svn/refs/remotes/trunk/.rev_map.f0385452-2b02-e011-bae3-001e4f1e4737 at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1554
```

I can't figure out how to get past it.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error after a system crash. The following worked for me:

1. delete file .git/svn/refs/remotes/trunk/.rev_map.f0385452-2b02-e011-bae3-001e4f1e4737
2. Replace the hash for refs/remotes/trunk/ in .git/packed-refs by the hash of the previous revision.
3. run git fetch. It should first rebuild the .rev_map file.

I also ran git pack-refs --all at some point, but I think that didn't have an effect.

I was guided by this:
[I need to un-fetch some revisions from git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105064/i-need-to-un-fetch-some-revisions-from-git-svn)

Comment: For my part, I just did the step 1 to make it work again.